# Trouble with Gson Exclusion Strategy

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I am using Gson to serialize a custom object. I have defined an exclusion strategy as follows -

```
public class HumidityExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        System.out.println(f.getName());

        boolean result = (f.getAnnotation(Expose.class) == null)
                || (f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("humidity")
                && UserInputThread.shouldExcludeHumidity);

        System.out.println(result);

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I initialize the Gson instance like this, in another class -

```
private static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder()
                  .setExclusionStrategies(new HumidityExclusionStrategy())
                  .create();
```

`UserInputThread.shouldExcludeHumidity` is a boolean that is modified based on some user input. When I use the Gson object to serialize for the first time (`GSON.toJson(sensor)`), the print statements in the `shouldSkipField()` method of the strategy do their work, and I get the expected output.

But when the value of `UserInputThread.shouldExcludeHumidity` changes, the result of the next serialization is the same as the first - the humidity field is included. Also, the print statements do not print anything to the console. Why is this happening ?

I have checked the value of the boolean `UserInputThread.shouldExcludeHumidity`, and it is what I expect it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for this problem. Internally, gson caches the result of an exclusion strategy using a map, in the `Gson.java` class.

In order to get the intended results, I had to initialize a new Gson object each time I needed to serialize. This solution might pose a performance issue, but for my case, performance is not really a problem and this method works.

Instead of creating a global Gson object and using it whenever necessary, I use the following method call -

```
private Gson getGson() {
    return new GsonBuilder()
                .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                .setExclusionStrategies(strat)
                .create();
}
```

Old -

```
private final Gson gson = new .....;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ..... gson.toJson(...); .....
}
```

New -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ..... getGson().toJson(...); .....
}
```